# react-native display only one kind of data : "cannot read property ... of undefined

Tags: android, ios, firebase, react-native

I have a screen representing the opening hours of a business.

I store the hours from my input like this:

```
                <FormLabel labelStyle={styles.formLabel}>de: </FormLabel>
                <CustomInput
                  underlineColorAndroid="#58CAF1"
                  style={styles.inputScheduleTime}
                  // ref="lundiStart"
                  placeholder="8H00..."
                  keyboardType="numeric"
                  onBlur={ input => {

                      let input1 = input.nativeEvent.text;
                      this.setState({ monday: {
                        start: input1 ,
                        end: "",
                        selected: this.state.monday.selected
                        }
                      });
                  }
                }
                />
                <CustomInput
                  underlineColorAndroid="#58CAF1"
                  style={styles.inputScheduleTime}
                  // ref="lundiStart"
                  placeholder="8H00..."
                  keyboardType="numeric"
                  onBlur={ input => {
                    let input2 = input.nativeEvent.text;
                      this.setState({ monday: {
                        start:this.state.monday.start + ':' + input2,
                        end: "",
                        selected: this.state.monday.selected
                        }
                      });
                  }
                }
                /> ...
```

then on a second screen, I fill in an object to update my data on firebase:

```
if (this.state.monday.selected == true) {
      this.user.monday = this.state.monday;
      console.log(this.state.monday)
    } ...
```

When I want to read my data on u. The other screen I proceed as follows:

```
}).then((userData) => {
    //Schedule :
    if (userData.monday.start !== "" || userData.monday.end !== "" && userData.monday.selected == true) {
    this.setState({
        schedule :   {Lundi: userData.monday},
      // days: ['Lundi']

      });
    } else  {
      this.setState({
          schedule :  { },
        //  days: [" "]
      });
    } ...
```

Then I have a function to display my schedules:

```
  renderScheduleDay(){
    return Object.keys(this.state.schedule)
         .map((schedule, key) => (
          <View key={key} style={styles.containerSchedule}>
            <CheckBox
                  title={schedule}
                  containerStyle={styles.containerStyle}
                  checked
                />
              <Text>
                {this.state.schedule[schedule]['start'] !== null || this.state.schedule[schedule]['end'] !== null ?`Ouvert de  ${this.state.schedule[schedule]['start']} h à ${this.state.schedule[schedule]['end']} h` : 'fermé !'}
              </Text>

          </View>
        ));
}
```

I want to display only the days on which the data is present and/or updated but I have this error: **"Cannot read property' start' of undefined"**??

Maybe the way I set the state?
Or my data rendering condition?

Comment: Can you mention you state defination ? It cant access `start` of `monday`  obj. You need to define state like 
`state = {
    monday:{

    }
}`

Comment: in the screen where are my inputs the state is like this : ```state= {monday: {start: "",end: "",selected: false} ...```   And in the second screen before update it's like this: ```state = {monday: this.props.state.monday```

Comment: Ohh, can you show the Component calling Code ? `this.props.state.monday` this means props name is state right ? Like `<Screen2 state={this.state}/>`

Comment: That's what I'm actually using react-native-router-flux.
and I'm passing my state through my props route.
but this is my component  : https://codepen.io/e-noumene/pen/ZxWZPp